# LetsEncrypt certificates fails on Android phones running Android 7 or older

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, elliptic-curve, lets-encrypt-webapp-renewer

Hi have setup a small serve, generated a free certificate from Let's encrypt and configured in apache to use that certificate (fullchain.pem and privkey.pem)

However, when I attempt to make a call from my Android app I get this error

java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found
Is Let's encrypt root certificate not trusted by the Android cert trust store? Or did I miss something when setting up apache? What is a work around for this If i still want to use Let's encrypt certificates?